# Why does Tika add extra whitespaces when converting pdf to html?

Tags: java, html, pdf, text, apache-tika

I have text in word document, that I then saved as pdf file. When I convert the pdf to html using Apache Tika it adds extra whitespaces between sentences and truncates the sentences. But I want that the pdf coverts to html without those whitespaces and sentence truncations.

**The code I used for converting pdf to html:**

```
try {
            File file = new File("path/to/pdf");
            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(file.toURI()));

            Parser tikaParser = new AutoDetectParser();;
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Metadata metaData = new Metadata();
            ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
            SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();

            TransformerHandler textHandler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
            textHandler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "html");
            textHandler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
            textHandler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "utf-8");
            textHandler.setResult(new StreamResult(out));

            ExpandedTitleContentHandler expandedTitleContentHandler = new ExpandedTitleContentHandler(textHandler);
            tikaParser.parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), expandedTitleContentHandler, metaData, context);

            String content= new String(out.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            return content;
} catch (TransformerConfigurationException | TikaException | SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**I want the html to look exactly as how pdf content looks like this:**
[image: The pdf content with the formatting that I want to keep]

**the html that is generated from the pdf content:**
[image]

As can be seen Tika adds extra whitespaces, truncates sentences and removes styling of pdf format.

**QUESTION:**

So how can I configure Tika or Tika AutoDetectParser to keep the formatting in the pdf file as it is and **NOT** truncate, add whitespaces and remove styling ?

**UPDATES:**

Apache Tika Core and Parsers packages version: 1.24.1

Comment: What version of Apache Tika are you using? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr 
The core and parsers libraries are of version 1.24.1

Comment: Did you try the PDF troubleshooting steps? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/Troubleshooting+Tika#TroubleshootingTika-PDFTextProblems

Comment: @Gagravarr Yes I tested it with these steps and it extracted the text in txt file without any errors, it is the way that it generated the text which is problematic, because it cuts all of the sentences after some length (to make text in an even column I believe) as shown in the question. So the problem is in how PDFBox is configured. But I am a beginner with PDFBox so I don't really know how to configure it in the way I want it.